# TCL TWAPI outvar in registered .net Core COM dll

Tags: c#, .net-core, com, tcl

While creating a basic classlib based on the guide by Mircorsoft
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com). I get a tiny COM class returning Pi - Everything works just fine.

Problems occure while changing the result to an output variable rather than the return value:

```
public string ComputePi(out string result) {
   ...
   double piResult = 4.0 * sum;
   result = piResult.ToString();
   return "done";
}
```

In tcl with twapi the outvariable is not generated on tcl side (twapi 4.7.2 tcl 8.6).
Not working example in tcl:

```
package require twapi
set handle [::twapi::comobj ComTest.Application]
$handle ComputePi result
puts $result
```

I've tested the same COM class with powershell and VBS, and it worked as expected in those languages. Working example in vbs:

```
Set myObject = CreateObject("ComTest.Application")
myObject.ComputePi test
msgbox test
```

The twapi call works also just fine with another registered COM-Class on my maschine, so I guess there is probably some kind of mandatory build option to get this .Net Core COM to work flawlessly with tcl twapi.

**Update 28.08.2023**

As suggested in the comments I made some tests on the interfaces. Turns out that my classlib with targetFramework set to net7.0 behaves to twapi like a classlib with not dedicated interface defined.
While putting the very same code to a TargetFrameworkVersion v4.8 project it works well.
Here is my definition of the interface, which seems not to work when compiled to net7.0 and used by twapi:

```
   [ComVisible(true)]
   [Guid("fe45fc36-c5b9-4499-8d31-7f5db7d4a12f")]
   public interface OwnInterface
    {
      string ComputePi(out string result);
    }
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("BA9AC84B-C7FC-41CF-8B2F-1764EB773D4B")]
       public class Application : OwnInterface {
          public string ComputePi(out string result )
          ...
```

Comment: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/upvar

Comment: @HansPassant in the script example I'm already at top level - and well yes the package twapi isn't upvaring anything through the comobj call. Somehow the result parameter is not recognized internally from twapi as an out parameter.

Comment: Yes, TCL doesn't really support pass-by-reference parameters.  The odds that upvar could work for interop calls is surely very low.  Do check if the function return value is passed, that would be your only backdoor to get values out of interop calls.

Comment: What does this method `$handle -print` do ?

Comment: -print gives a `Windows error: -2146234011`

Comment: Okay, try this `$handle ComputePi [twapi::outvar result] ; puts $result`

Comment: @Mkn using the outvar results in an existing variable with the value `0` which is not the value written to the out variable. I've updated my post - seems to be something with the Interace.

Comment: sorry, I have no other solution, maybe you can contact the [author](https://sourceforge.net/p/twapi/bugs/)